# Why was Daphne able to walk while her ability was suppressed?

Tags: heroes

During the solar eclipse in [The Eclipse, Part 1](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1185908/?ref_=tt_ep_pr) (season 3, episode 10), Daphne was shown in leg braces and crutches, so it seems her ability granted her the ability to stand and walk, in addition to super speed.

The Haitian's ability has been shown to be an off-switch - either you can use your ability around him, or you can't - there's no middle ground, no grey area.

Why then, in [One of Us, One of Them](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1185913/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) (season 3, episode 3), is she shown walking around, despite being under the influence of the Haitian's suppression?

Comment: If I had to guess, it's due to the writers forgetting how they'd established her powers.  They did this from time to time (such as showing Sylar struggling to read Noah's lips because the writers forgot he had super hearing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The Haitian's ability has been shown to be an off-switch - either you can use your ability around him, or you can't - there's no middle ground, no grey area.

I think your misremembering the Haitian's power. He didn't have an "off switch" on people's powers; he had the power to severally dampen them. Most of the time this amounted to the same thing. But you'll recall that in Season One episode "Fallout," Matt Parkman manages, with extreme effort, to read Noah Bennett's mind for a split second and hear the name "Sylar."

Presumably, the same thing happens with Daphne: her power has been extremely limited, to the extent that she can no longer run at near light speed. But she can still barely use her power to walk.